# Dapper - Sql to Object implicit cast from string to int

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm using dapper and am having issues with casting a string value from the db to an int. Has anyone overriden the TypeMap to allow for this?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dapper is picky about the types it maps. This protects you from all sorts of nasty errors that pop up later.

For example, your db could return:

- `010hello`
- `10a10`
- `374837483748374837483748374834784378437438743874384738473`

There is no clear course of action for mapping this kind of stuff to an `Int32`

That said, there are two strategies you can follow with dapper that do not require changes to IL generation.

Option 1: Shadow property

```
class Foo
{
   public int Age 
   { 
      get 
      { 
       int age; 
       int.TryParse(ageString, out age); 
       return age;  
      } 
   }
   string ageString;
}

\\ usage
cnn.Query<Foo>("select ageString from TableWithString");
```

Option 2, cast in SQL

```
cnn.Query<Bar>("select cast(ageString as int) Age from TableWithString");
```

---

There is no clean way to extend the mapping functionality in Dapper, if you do so you will be stuck needing to merge any fixes we add over time to your local copy.

Comment: Great thanks. I was thinking about Option 1, but wanted to see if there was other solutions.